# How to create an NFT collection sale validator script

Tags: plutus, nft

If I have a wallet that currently stores x amount of NFT's and I make a validator script that provides one NFT from that wallet in exchange for ADA what would I call to make sure 1 unique NFT goes out to each caller of the said validator script? Specifically how would the validator script know which NFT to give out? Is there a way to sort out metadata of NFT's using script context and pick the next NFT to send out by its number order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are onchain validator scripts available like this one, which describe nicely how it can be done.

[nft-plutus by Berry Pool](https://github.com/Berry-Pool/nft-plutus/blob/main/src/cardano/nft/onchain.hs)

Answer (score -2):

The way that my vending machine does it is that I store all of the total NFT collection in a MongoDB. Then, when my script sees a sale UTXO come into a wallet, it queries the MongoDB for any NFT that is still 'available' and pulls them all down into an array. I then shuffle the array and mint the one in the [0] spot. Finally, I mark the NFT as sold in MongoDB.

Comment: This question is about plutus, not offchain solutions.